# HandleMessage Failed to Pass Object

Tags: android, handler

I'm receiving data through a Bluetooth Service and would like to pass it to MainActivity with handleMessage, MainActivity has received the message but the object was "null"...Can anyone advise? Thanks in advance!

In Bluetooth Service: (the variable *data* is a String.)
`mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_ADD_ENTRY_L, data).sendToTarget();`

In MainActivity:
problem- String *data* here is null, while I have double checked the *data* sent from bluetooth service is not null.

> D/Main Activity: data at handler: null

```
        mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull final Message msg) {
            switch ((msg.what)) {                
                case MessageConstants.MESSAGE_ADD_ENTRY_L:
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "handler add entry");
                        Thread dataParseThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String data = (String) msg.obj;
                                Log.d(TAG, "data at handler: " + data);
                                SensorData.parseDataL(data))
                                exportData.logEntryL();                                  
                            }
                        });
                        dataParseThread.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "handler went wrong: " + e);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `sendToTarget()` make sure your target is pointing to your `mHandler` as in

```
Message message = new Message();
message.what = MainActivity.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_ADD_ENTRY_L;
message.setData(data);
message.setTarget(mHandler);
message.sendToTarget();
```

**UPDATE**

you can still use your existing approach to get `data` as `Object`, but at some point you need to set the `Target` to `Message` so it can post

```
Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_ADD_ENTRY_L, data);
message.setTarget(mHandler);
message.sendToTarget();
```

Comment: Thank you. May I know in the case, if data inside set.Data have to be a bundle?
I'm also concerning if this will take longer time to process, comparing to directly passing this data to MainActivity. (i.e. in Bluetooth Service, I put MainActivity.data = data) Since I'm receiving data and parsing at 50Hz, I'm afraid this would slower the process.. Or by putting into a thread in this way won't block the process?

Comment: I have updated the answer close to your use case

Comment: Thank you, it works! I also figured out that I have to assign the string into data, String data = (String) msg.obj; before I start a thread, and declare it as final in order to make it work.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you my answer helped you solve, please accept it:)